# Pointer function argument corrupted, Stack corruption?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, parameters, ctypes

Im building a C++ library which gets called by python via ctypes. The function has as parameter a pointer to a struct and passes it to other (internal) function. It looks like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void USBEndpoint_subscribe(USBEndpoint* endpoint, CALLBACK callback) {
  try {
    subscribe_internal(endpoint, callback);
  } catch (int e_code) {
    exception_report(__FILE__, __LINE__, e_code); \
  } catch (...) {
    exception_report(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

void subscribe_internal(USBEndpoint* endpoint, CALLBACK callback)
{
  ...
}
```

The thing is that the value for endpoint recieved at USBEndpoint_subscribe is not the same value that enters subscribe_internal. For example:

while debugging I can see that USBEndpoint_subscribe recieves:
endpoint=0x00000000088f0680 (and callback=0x0000000000540f50)

and as soon as I step into subscribe_internal, inside subscribe_internal the values are:
endpoint=0x000007fef15f7740 (and callback=0x0000000000000000).

I have not spawn other threads and I'm compiling the library in release mode**. My only suspect could be stack corruption, but actually I have clue of what's going on.

Any hints of what can be happening are very welcome.

** I have compiled python in debug mode, but it's slow to set up with spider and I loose the interactive console if I use my debug-compiled version, so I prefer sticking with release python and compiling my library in release.

EDIT:

As suggested, I used my debug version of python with a debug compile of the library. But I still got the same behavior (endpoint: 0x0000000002be80e0->0x0000000000000000, callback: 0x0000000000320f88->0x00000000024d24b8). No other useful information appeared here that wasn't in release mode.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is x86-64 on Windows?

Comment: It may be inconvenient, but you probably should break down and use a debug build.  Release builds typical strip all the debug symbols and perform optimizations that can cause the debugger to display some unexpected results.

Comment: Yes, this is x64 on windows.

Comment: I think you should try stepping through in assembler mode, and see what instructions are being executed.  Are the types of the two arguments actually both `USBEndpoint*`, or have you simplified for exposition?  If one is actually a base class of the other, there might be a pointer adjustment required.

Comment: @MartinBonner Debugging in assembler mode I can see that the calling convention is not right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was loading The library using CDLL("path"), which makes the calling convention cdecl. And even if I'm compiling in VS2008 with /Gd, it seems it's using other convention. Appending __cdecl to the function declaration solves the issue.

Comment: `__cdecl` should be the default for an x86 target. For x64, `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` are ignored; the compiler uses the Windows x64 calling convention unless `__vectorcall` is indicated.